# Data from firebase not ordering correctly when performing a join

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get my data chronological from firebase. I'm using .push to store the data so it should give me the data chronological and when I not perform the "join" it works without problems.

```
export const getMessages = (groupId) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: GET_MESSAGES });
  firebase.database().ref(`/chats/${groupId}/messages`)
    .on('value', snapshot => {
      msgArray = [];
      snapshot.forEach((child) => {
        let children = child.val();
        // join to get the name
        firebase.database().ref(`/users/${children.from}/`)
          .once('value', snap => {
            children.creatorName = snap.val().name;
            msgArray.unshift(children);
          })
          .then(() => {
            dispatch({ type: GET_MESSAGES_SUCCESS, payload: msgArray });
          })
          .catch((e) => console.log(e));
        });
    });
};
```

The outcome when I render is it something like this:

```
Max - 2 hours ago - Hello
Max - 3 hours ago - How are you?
Max - 4 hours ago - What's up
Max - 5 hours ago - ...
Alex - 2 hours ago - Hello
Alex - 3 hours ago - Fine thank you
Alex - 4 hours ago - What's up
Alex - 5 hours ago - ...
```

But it should be like this:

```
Max - 2 hours ago - Hello
Alex - 2 hours ago - Hello
Max - 3 hours ago - How are you?
Alex - 3 hours ago - Fine thank you
...
```

What am I doing wrong here?

This is where I render it:

```
renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    if (item.from === this.props.userKey) {
      return (
        <OwnMessage
          time={moment(item.timestamp).fromNow()}
          messageText={item.messageText}
          from={item.creatorName}
        />
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <OthersMessage
          time={moment(item.timestamp).fromNow()}
          messageText={item.messageText}
          from={item.creatorName}
        />
      );
    }
  };
```

This is a screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of the rendered Chat-Component]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wait for all the firebase promises to resolve and then `sort` your `msgArray` before dispatching `GET_MESSAGE_SUCCESS`.

**Example**

```
export const getMessages = groupId => dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: GET_MESSAGES });

  firebase
    .database()
    .ref(`/chats/${groupId}/messages`)
    .on("value", snapshot => {
      const promises = [];

      snapshot.forEach(child => {
        const children = child.val();

        const promise = firebase
          .database()
          .ref(`/users/${children.from}/`)
          .once("value")
          .then(snap => {
            children.creatorName = snap.val().name;

            return children;
          });

        promises.push(promise);
      });

      Promise.all(promises)
        .then(msgArray => {
          msgArray.sort((a, b) => {
            if (a.timestap < b.timestamp) {
              return -1;
            } else if (a.timestamp > b.timestamp) {
              return 1;
            } else {
              return 0;
            }
          });

          dispatch({ type: GET_MESSAGES_SUCCESS, payload: msgArray });
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I really appreciate that. When I try your code it gives me an error because of the .map() function. I tried to use forEach instead. With forEach it won't give me an error but somehow it doesn't render anything.

Comment: @Zander You're welcome! That's frustrating. What error are you getting with `map`?

Comment: I'm getting: "undefined is not a function (evaluating 'snapshot.map')"

Comment: @Zander Ah, excuse me. I thought `snapshot` was a regular array. I updated the answer with `forEach` instead.